# converting a Haskell function into java "function"

Tags: java, haskell, java-8, java-stream

I have this function in Haskell, and I am wondering how it can be converted to Java, especially using streams:

```
build = [(w,m,n,g) | w <- [240..1280], m <- [2,4..20], n <- [2..100], g <- [240..1280], ((w - 2*m - n*g) `mod` (n+1) == 0), n*g+2*m <= w, n*g <= w]
```

Comment: I don't know haskell, but if you are willing to explain what it does...

Comment: Sorry for the direct question. The code is a function that builds a list, and each element of the produced list is a tuple (with four elements: w, m, n, g). Each one of these elements is itself drawn from a corresponding list, and then these elements are subject to certain constraints.

Comment: Probably, my question could be asked better in the following way, though I appreciate a direct answer to the above code snippet:

is there in java something like Tuples in Haskell?

Comment: this is ain't going to be a walk in the park... java does not have `Tuple`, at all. So your best bet would be `List<List<...>>` which ain't pretty; but possible. Generally if would make your requirements understandable, this could be done - but Java Functional very much `!=` haskell functional

Comment: @HassanShahin unfortunately your question is _too broad_. have a look at [**java.util.stream**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) package for classes that support functional-style operations on streams of elements and also see the [**java.util.function**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) package for the available functional interfaces. once you make an attempt and you're stuck feel free to come back with that you've tried.

Comment: @Aominè Thanks, I will.

Comment: Voting to reopen. While general questions of converting Haskell to Java are certainly too broad, the example in this question is simple enough to convert, and it raises some interesting issues. I decided to think about this whilst in the shower, but you guys were too quick to close it. (Either that or I'm too slow in the shower.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(I'm not a Haskell expert, but I know enough to be dangerous.)

The example code given has several Haskell constructs that map reasonably
well into Java constructs:

- A Haskell list is lazy, so it corresponds to a Java Stream.
- The ranges used are of integers, so they correspond to IntStream.
  For example, `[240..1280]` corresponds to `IntStream.rangeClosed(240, 1280)`.
- A range with a step has no direct correspondence in Java, but it can easily
  be computed; you just have to do a bit of arithmetic and then map the values
  from the sequential range to the one with steps. For example, `[2, 4..20]`
  can be written as

  ```
  IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10).map(i -> 2 * i)
  ```
- A condition on a list comprehension corresponds to filtering a stream through
  a predicate.
- A comprehension with multiple generators corresponds to flatmapping
  of nested streams.
- There is no general way to represent tuples in Java. Various third party
  libraries provide tuple implementations with varying tradeoffs regarding
  generics and boxing. Or, you can just write your own class with the fields
  you want. (This can be quite tedious if you use lots of different kinds of
  tuples, though.) In this case, the tuple is simply four ints, so it's easily
  represented using an int array with four elements.

Putting it all together, we get the following.

```
static Stream<int[]> build() {
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(240, 1280).boxed()
               .flatMap(w -> IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10).map(m -> 2 * m).boxed()
                   .flatMap(m -> IntStream.rangeClosed(2, 100).boxed()
                       .flatMap(n -> IntStream.rangeClosed(240, 1280)
                                              .filter(g -> ((w - 2*m - n*g) % (n+1) == 0))
                                              .filter(g -> n*g+2*m <= w)
                                              .filter(g -> n*g <= w)
                                              .mapToObj(g -> new int[] { w, m, n, g }))));
}
```

This is clearly quite verbose compared to the original Haskell, but you can easily see where the Haskell constructs have ended up in the Java code. I believe this is correct, as it seems to generate the same output as the Haskell code.

Note that we are generating values using `IntStream` but we want the flatmap to give a stream of arrays (which are objects), whereas `IntStream.flatMap` returns an `IntStream`. Perhaps ideally there would be a `flatMapToObj` operation, but there isn't, so we must box the int value into an `Integer` object and then call `Stream.flatMap` it.

One could assign the stream pipeline to a variable of type Stream, but this wouldn't be very convenient, as Java streams can be used at most once. Since constructing such a stream is cheap (compared to evaluating it) it's reasonable to write a function `build()` that returns a freshly created stream, ready to be evaluated by the caller.

When the following Java code is run,

```
    System.out.println(build().count());
    System.out.println(build().findFirst().map(Arrays::toString).orElse("not found"));
    System.out.println(build().reduce((a, b) -> b).map(Arrays::toString).orElse("not found"));
```

the result is:

```
654559
[484, 2, 2, 240]
[1280, 20, 5, 248]
```

Running the following Haskell code (the definition of `build` is copied from the question)

```
build = [(w,m,n,g) | w <- [240..1280], m <- [2,4..20], n <- [2..100], g <- [240..1280],
                     ((w - 2*m - n*g) `mod` (n+1) == 0), n*g+2*m <= w, n*g <= w]

main = do
    print (length build)
    print (head build)
    print (last build)
```

gives the following output:

```
654559
(484,2,2,240)
(1280,20,5,248)
```

So the transliteration appears correct to my eye.

Times for the `head` (in Java, `findFirst`) and `last` (in Java, `reduce((a, b) -> b)`) operations were as follows: (updated using GHC 7.6.3 -O2)

```
       head     last
GHC      8s      36s
JDK      3s       9s
```

This at least shows that both systems provide laziness, as the computation is short-circuited after the first element is found, whereas finding the last element requires all to be computed.

Interestingly, in Haskell, calling all three of `length`, `head`, and `last` doesn't take any more time than just calling `last` (around 36s) presumably because of memoization. There's no memoization in Java, but of course you could explicitly store the results in an array or List and process that multiple times.

Overall, though, I was startled at how much faster the Java implementation is. I don't really understand Haskell performance, so I'll leave it to Haskell experts to comment on that. It's quite possible I've done something wrong, though mostly I just copied the function from the question into a file and compiled it using GHC.

My environment:

JDK 9, GHC 7.6.3 -O2, MacBook Pro mid 2014 2-core 3GHz Intel Core i7

Comment: You can avoid boxing by replacing `.boxed().flatMap(...)` with `.mapToObj(...).flatMap(Function.identity())`.

Comment: @Stuart Marks Many many thanks for insisting to re-open the question. (I thought I was doing some harm because of the negative rating). Secondly thanks for the code, and yes! it produces the same results. Thirdly, thanks for the great clarification of the logic to building the code.

Comment: @Eugene: Thanks for accepting and voting to re-open the question.

Comment: Very interesting. A bit more about performance. if we merge all the condition in one filter: `filter(g -> (((w - 2 * m - n * g) % (n + 1) == 0)) && (n * g + 2 * m <= w) && (n * g <= w)) `, the performance can be improved about 30%. if we use parallel stream, the speed will be almost doubled by the test on my laptop.

Comment: About the Haskell being slow, since you didn't mention it I'm guessing you compiled without optimizations. The -O2 compiler flag turns them on. Also GHC 7.6.3 is quite old.

Comment: @Potato44 Ah! I compiled with -O2 with 7.6.3 and times were considerably faster, though still not quite as fast as Java. I've edited the answer with these times. I also tried out GHC 8.2.1 with -O2 but oddly enough things were considerably slower than 7.6.3: 26s for `head` and 107s for all ops. Any ideas?

Comment: @StuartMarks What happens if you use `Int`s instead of `Integer`s in Haskell (`build :: [(Int, Int, Int, Int)]`)? I get a good speedup.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex I changed the comprehension to use `(w::Int,m::Int,n::Int,g::Int)` and speed improved to about 5s for `head` and 22s for all ops. Is there a better way to use `Int` instead of `Integer`?

Comment: @StuartMarks I could have not even imagined I would be so happy re-opening a closed question. thank u so much

Comment: @123-xyz: Do you think we can we get more performance in the Haskell function if we combine the conditions into one condition, the same way as you suggested for Java filters?